# TypeOrm Error: No connection options were found in any orm configuration files

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm working on a Typescript/nodeJS personal project. I want to create a connection to my postgres database using typeOrm but I ran into this issue:

here is the full error:

```
$ ts-node src/index.ts
Version 9 of Highlight.js has reached EOL and is no longer supported. Please upgrade to version 10.
Server listening at http://localhost:3002
(node:36885) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No connection options were found in any orm configuration files.
    at connexion_1.createConnection.error (/home/maxime/Dev/JeuxDuPlacard/packages/server/src/index.ts:7:36)
    at typeorm_1.getConnectionOptions.then.catch.error (/home/maxime/Dev/JeuxDuPlacard/packages/server/src/technical/typeorm/connexion.ts:17:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/maxime/Dev/JeuxDuPlacard/packages/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/_bin.ts:182:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
(node:36885) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:36885) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

**my project structure**

```
.
├── docker
│   ├── database.env
│   └── docker-compose.yml
├── ormconfig.ts
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── app.ts
│   ├── business
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── technical
│       ├── controller
│       ├── typeorm
│       │   ├── connexion.ts
│       │   └── repository
│       ├── user
│       └── validation
├── tsconfig.json
├── yarn-error.log
└── yarn.lock
```

**./package.json**

```
{
   "name": "server",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "main": "index.js",
   "license": "MIT",
   "type": "commonjs",
   "workspaces": [
      "packages/*"
   ],
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
      "dev": "tsc --watch",
      "test": "echo testing server",
      "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
      "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
      "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
      "pg": "^8.4.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "typeorm": "0.2.29",
      "validate.js": "^0.13.1"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
      "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
      "@types/node": "^14.14.8",
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0",
      "typescript": "^4.0.5"
   }
}
```

**src/index.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection } from "./technical/typeorm/connexion";
import app from './app';

const port = 3002;

createConnection( error => { throw new Error(error.message) });

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

**src/technical/typeorm/connection.ts**

```
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';
import { getConnectionOptions, createConnection as TypeOrmCreateConnexion, Connection } from 'typeorm';

export async function createConnection(handleError: (error: Error) => unknown): Promise<Connection>{
  return getConnectionOptions()
    .then(connectionOptions => {
      console.log(connectionOptions)
       return TypeOrmCreateConnexion({ 
        ...(connectionOptions as PostgresConnectionOptions),
        poolErrorHandler: handleError,
        extra: {
          max: 1
        },
      })
    })
  .catch(error => {
    handleError(error);
    throw error;
  })
}
```

**ormConfig.ts**

```
import {ConnectionOptions} from "typeorm";
import path from "path";

const isCompiled = path.extname(__filename).includes('js');

const fileExtension = isCompiled ? "js" : "ts";

export default {
   type: "postgres",
   host: process.env.DB_HOST || "localhost",
   port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT) || 5432,
   username: process.env.DB_USERNAME || "test",
   password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || "test",
   database: process.env.DB_NAME || "test",
   synchronize: true,
   logging: false,
   entities: [
      `src/business/**/*.entity.${fileExtension}`
   ],
   migrations: [
      `src/migration/**/*.${fileExtension}`
   ],
   subscribers: [
      `src/subscriber/**/*.${fileExtension}`
   ]
} as ConnectionOptions;
```

Apparently, typeOrm cannot find the ormConfig.ts file. This project is part of a larger monorepo which also contains the front-end connected with workspaces and lerna (I can provide more information if needed)

Any help coming from someone who can help me to find the solution about why typeORM can't find this ormConfig file will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to use TypeORM configuration file from the root of the project, then it should be one of the next formats: .js, .json, .xml, .env, .yml, .xml ([doc](https://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/creating-a-new-connection-from-the-configuration-file)) (also suggest to use ormconfig without capital C).